# my SCSS style is not working at all in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

i am trying to do my Front with React and Sass, i installed Sass with the command, yarn add sass everything normal. But when i define all my components in the scss file my site and my files .jsx does not link or that it ´s  what i think, i did not get errors on my cmd or javascript console.
here is the code and the pictures

```
import React from 'react'

const Login = () => {

    return (

        <div className="auth" >  

        <h1>Login </h1>
        
        <form> 

<input type="text" placeholder="set your username "/> 
<input type="password" placeholder="set your password"/> 
<button>Login</button>


        </form>
        </div>
        
    )


}

export default Login
```

scss

```
$lightGreen: #b9e7e7;

.app {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  .container {
    width: 1024px;

    .link {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: inherit;
    }
    //LOGIN & REGISTER

    .auth {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: $lightGreen;

      h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        color: teal;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }

      form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        width: 200px;
        gap: 20px;

        input {
          padding: 10px;
          border: none;
          border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
        }

        button {
          padding: 10px;
          border: none;
          background-color: teal;
          cursor: pointer;
          color: white;
        }

        p {
          font-size: 12px;
          color: red;
          text-align: center;
        }

        span {
          font-size: 12px;
          text-align: center;
        }
      }
    }

}
}

import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Link,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import Register from "./pages/Register"
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Single from "./pages/Single";
import Write from "./pages/Write";

const Layout = () => {

  return (
  
  
  <>
  <Navbar/>
  <Outlet/>
  <Footer/>
  
  </>
  
  
  );

};



const router = createBrowserRouter([
  
  {
    path: "/",
   element: <Layout/>,
   children: [
     {

      path: "/",
      element: <Home/>
     },
     {

      path: "/single",
      element: <Single/>

     },

     {

      path: "/write",
      element: <Write/>
     },

   ]
  },
  {
    path: "/register",
   element: <Register/> 
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
   element: <Login/> 
  },

  

]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="container"> 
        <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </div>
    </div>
  );

}




export default App;
```

This is what i get... Just like if i was made nothing with styles.

[image]

Project folder order

[image]

Comment: Are you importing the styles anywhere?

Comment: no i dont, i tried to import but i did not know the syntax to do. If you can tell me any correctly form to import. –

Comment: Is this `nextJS` or just a "normal" React app?

Comment: a normal React-app

Comment: you need to import the sass file and make sure you have the loader in your react app to compile it.  If you don't know how to do that then the answers on this may give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52406396/how-to-include-sass-file-in-reactjs

Comment: can you tell how to import, cause i tried to do like css file but i didnt work, css is not the same.

Comment: Well a good way of doing it would be to co-locate each component's style with its code instead of having one large file. Makes it easier to manage. [Here's some video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFA-ZJ9KTqs).

Comment: ok let me do it i will comment you anything